# for each mysql create submit with javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

Currently the table shows a different button for each mysql row, but only the first mysql row button works properly. When it works properly, the submit button saves the location row as a value for a javascript AJAX post. When it doesn't work properly the submit button refreshes the page.

This is the html and mysql form:

```
   while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

echo '<form class="form-signin" action="" method="POST" id="register-form"><tr>';
echo "<td><b>" . $row['product'] . "</b><br>";
echo "<td><b>" . $row['location'] . "</b><br>";
echo "" . $row['notes'] . "";
  echo '  
  <input type="hidden" name="user_name" value="'.   $row['product'].'" />
   <input type="hidden" name="location" value="'.   $row['location'].'" />
  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Table Number" name="user_email" id="user_email" />
  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Quantity" name="password" id="user_email" />
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Submit form" name="btn-save" id="btn-submit">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> &nbsp;'. $row['location'] .'
            </button></td>';

echo "</tr></form>";

}
```

This is the javascript for "register-form" that posts:

```
{
    var data = $("#register-form").serialize();

    $.ajax({

        type: 'POST',
        url: 'register.php',
        data: data,
        beforeSend: function() {
            $("#error").fadeOut();
            $("#btn-submit").html('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-transfer"></span> &nbsp; sending ...');
        },
        success: function(data) {}
    })
}
```

Basically if the submit button is clicked need it to save for the respective row that is clicked, instead of taking a different action.

```
$('document').ready(function()
{
    /* validation */
    $("#register-form").validate({
        rules:
        {

        },
        messages:
        {
            user_name: "Enter a Valid Username",
            password:{
                required: "Provide a Password",
                minlength: "Password Needs To Be Minimum of 8 Characters"
            },
            user_email: "Enter a Valid Email",
            cpassword:{
                required: "Retype Your Password",
                equalTo: "Password Mismatch! Retype"
            }
        },
        submitHandler: submitForm
    });
    /* validation */

    /* form submit */
    function submitForm()
    {
        var data = $("#register-form").serialize();

        $.ajax({

            type : 'POST',
            url  : 'register.php',
            data : data,
            beforeSend: function()
            {
                $("#error").fadeOut();
                $("#btn-submit").html('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-transfer"></span> &nbsp; sending ...');
            },
            success :  function(data)
            {
                if(data==1){

                    $("#error").fadeIn(1000, function(){


                        $("#error").html('<div class="alert alert-danger"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></span> &nbsp; Sorry email already taken !</div>');

                        $("#btn-submit").html('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> &nbsp; Create Account');

                    });

                }
                else if(data=="registered")
                {

                    $("#btn-submit").html('Ordered');
                   // setTimeout('$(".form-signin").fadeOut(500, function(){ $(".signin-form").load(""); }); ',5000);

                }
                else{

                    $("#error").fadeIn(1000, function(){

                        $("#error").html('<div class="alert alert-danger"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></span> &nbsp; '+data+' !</div>');

                        $("#btn-submit").html('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> &nbsp; Create Account');

                    });

                }
            }
        });
        return false;
    }
    /* form submit */

});
```

Comment: ids are the same across the number of rows you get from MY SQL e.g. you get 10 rows back, only the first one would work because id `btn-submit` is the same across all those rows. That said, to resolve it one way or the other you should let us know how you have defined the click event? if you have attached the click event to the  element by id then yes there is your issue and so you need to attach the click event using some other selector (element/class etc)

Comment: I added the event with an edit.

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure it is simply because you have all of the buttons with the same id which I think means all but the first will not be valid. Try adding the row id to the end of the id="btn-submit" and see if that works.

EDIT::

The javascript doesn't do anything because you are probably starting your click handler with something like:

```
 $('#submit-btn')...
```

right? (I cant see that part of the javascript in what you copied above.) If that is the case, what that little piece of codes says is

> find an element with the id=submit-btn and then run this code when that element is clicked.

What you need to have is:
`$('.row-submit-btn')....` instead. This is saying find an element with the css class of row-submit-btn and then run this code when one of them is clicked.

The reason I say to use a CSS class instead of the id is because id's have to be unique or the html is invalid (thus the reason this question is here!) but CSS Classes do not have this restriction. The major caveat here is that you need to make sure that this css class is unique to elements on this page (meaning there aren't any other things with row-submit-btn as a css class.) otherwise you will get unintended side effects.

Comment: This is the correct explanation why but not the correct way to fix the issue

Comment: Care to explain why it wouldnt work as I suggested? I have used that approach many, many times without fail.

Comment: I mean it would work if the javascript was altered to match, but there is also better ways to do it. It's not a bad answer, just needs some work

Comment: what would be the easiest way to do it Grumpy?

Comment: this isn't realistic because the javascript is looking for btn-submit only, not a mysql id

Comment: Then you shouldn't specify the id for the button at all and use a class selector to trigger the form post. Add something to the current css classes like row-submit-btn or something and then change the jquery to $('.row-submit-btn').on('click' .... (or whatever the start of the javascript is)

Comment: If I dont put an ID the javascript does nothing. I do not understand.